# Check change in background image on button

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I'm making a tests of my application and I have a table with cells, and in each cell have a button. When the user tap in button, the button's background image change.

I want a write a test of it, but how to check the changes of the background image?

```
func testChangeBackground() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tables = app.tables
    let firstCell = tables.cells.allElementsBoundByIndex.first!

    let button = firstCell.buttons.allElementsBoundByIndex.first!
    button.tap()
    ... ?
```

Comment: why don't you use a boolean to maintain the state rather than checking the background change! @Macabeus

Comment: have u tried by taking the background image as element? if you can get the background image as element, u can easily check it.

Comment: @Fay007 But how to check the state of a variable in ui-test? The memory of a application and ui-test isn't shared.

Comment: @noor How? I can't find it.

Comment: i just want to know, can you take the button images as xcuielement, is it exist? i think your button back ground images has a accessibilty id or level or vlaues. you can check it by comparing the xcuielement level or value or by identifier

Comment: @Macabeus sorry, I misunderstood your question and posted a completely different answer.